# Displaying dates where a count function returns nothing sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My sql table looks as below and contains the list of users who performed some action on the date:

```
| UPDATE_DATE | USER_ID |
|-------------|---------|
| 25/05/2021  | 3456    |
| 25/05/2021  | 3456    |
| 25/05/2021  | 56478   |
```

I would like generate a distinct count of users for the last 3 days, and where the count is 0 (and hence no corresponding date in the table) display that date in the table with a 0, i.e.

```
| UPDATE_DATE| COUNT_USER_ID |
|------------|---------------|
| 25/05/2021 | 2             |
| 24/05/2021 | 0             |
| 23/05/2021 | 0             |
```

However my query returns only dates that are available in the table :

```
select UPDATE_DATE, count(distinct(USER_ID) as COUNT_USER_ID
from my_table
where UPDATE_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE) - 3
group by UPDATE_DATE

| UPDATE_DATE| COUNT_USER_ID |
|------------|---------------|
| 25/05/2021 | 2             |
```

Is there a way to add those extra missing dates to my table?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a *calendar* which contains all dates you're interested in. A CTE is a simple way to accomplish that. Then outer join it to your "real" table and - that's it.

For sample data you posted, it would be

```
SQL> select * from test;

UPDATE_DAT    USER_ID
---------- ----------
25/05/2021       3456
25/05/2021       3456
25/05/2021      56478

SQL> with calendar (datum) as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 3
  5    )
  6  select c.datum as update_date,
  7    count(distinct t.user_id) count_user_id
  8  from calendar c left join test t on t.update_date = c.datum
  9  group by c.datum
 10  order by c.datum desc;

UPDATE_DAT COUNT_USER_ID
---------- -------------
25/05/2021             2
24/05/2021             0
23/05/2021             0

SQL>
```

Comment: Huh, right, @Gordon. The OP nicely wrote it, and I ignored what they said; stupid me. Thank you, fixed.